# KML time animation through TimeStamp

Tags: kml, timespan

I am facing a problem with the KML Function TimeStamp. I have PolygonObjects with defined TimeStamps for each object, including begin and end information. My question is the following: Is there an option that Polygons vanish at the defined end date? In my case the Polygons are shown up also after the defined end-time. I tried this also with KML-examples from the web. Or is there any other reason, why the end-tag is defined? Otherwise only using the begin-tag would give me the same result.

Attached there is the code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="Flood_2017_KML_AnimatonFormatted" id="Flood_2017_KML_AnimatonFormatted">
 <SimpleField name="ID" type="int"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="GlideNumbe" type="string"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="Country" type="string"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="OtherCount" type="string"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="long" type="float"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="lat" type="float"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="Area" type="float"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="Began" type="string"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="Ended" type="string"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="Validation" type="string"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="Dead" type="int"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="Displaced" type="int"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="MainCause" type="string"></SimpleField>
 <SimpleField name="Severity" type="float"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>Flood_2017_KML_AnimatonFormatted</name>
  <Style id="style1">
 <LineStyle>
  <color>40000000</color>
  <width>3</width>
 </LineStyle>
 <PolyStyle>
  <color>ffe7dcc3</color>
  <fill>1</fill>
  <outline>1</outline>
 </PolyStyle>
</Style>
  <Placemark>
  <TimeSpan>
 <begin>2017-01-05</begin>
 <end>2017-01-21</end>
  </TimeSpan>
 <styleUrl>#style1</styleUrl>
 <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
  <SimpleData name="ID">4435</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Country">Brazil</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="OtherCount">Argentina</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="long">-55.551237000000000</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="lat">-29.409362000000002</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Area">386846.737648000009358</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Began">2017/01/05</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/01/21</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Dead">0</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Displaced">0</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Severity">1.000000000000000</SimpleData>
 </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-50.157155,-29.908609 -52.829453,-32.783281 -57.184308,-30.500116 -60.747372,-27.423964 -60.94532,-26.035444 -54.808933,-26.831911 -50.157155,-29.908609</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
  <TimeSpan>
 <begin>2017-01-20</begin>
 <end>2017-01-21</end>
  </TimeSpan>
 <styleUrl>#style1</styleUrl>
 <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
  <SimpleData name="ID">4438</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Country">USA</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="long">-119.043052000000003</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="lat">35.083903999999997</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Area">74443.110646300003282</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Began">2017/01/20</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/01/21</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Dead">0</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Displaced">0</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Severity">1.000000000000000</SimpleData>
 </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-118.003825,33.546575 -119.191513,33.943864 -120.478175,34.341202 -121.170993,35.333279 -118.597669,36.621234 -116.915111,34.835276 -118.003825,33.546575</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
  <TimeSpan>
 <begin>2017-02-01</begin>
 <end>2017-02-07</end>
  </TimeSpan>
 <styleUrl>#style1</styleUrl>
 <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
  <SimpleData name="ID">4441</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Country">Peru</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="long">-77.572950000000006</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="lat">-5.250831000000000</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Area">288499.131403999985196</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Began">2017/02/01</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/02/07</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Dead">1</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Displaced">12000</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Severity">1.000000000000000</SimpleData>
 </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-78.859612,-8.472832 -80.740118,-5.695045 -79.255508,-4.505716 -77.57295,-2.721449 -74.405783,-2.02883 -74.702704,-5.995598 -78.859612,-8.472832</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
  <TimeSpan>
 <begin>2017-02-24</begin>
 <end>2017-03-03</end>
  </TimeSpan>
 <styleUrl>#style1</styleUrl>
 <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#Flood_2017_KML">
  <SimpleData name="ID">4445</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Country">Chile</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="long">-70.248874999999998</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="lat">-30.939481000000001</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Area">183781.025771999993594</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Began">2017/02/24</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Ended">2017/03/03</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Validation">News</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Dead">3</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Displaced">1200</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="MainCause">Heavy Rain</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="Severity">2.000000000000000</SimpleData>
 </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-70.644771,-35.947863 -72.030407,-36.04634 -71.733485,-32.277917 -71.634511,-29.699471 -70.842719,-26.129643 -69.852979,-25.832622 -68.467343,-26.626701 -69.358109,-28.411367 -69.951953,-30.4937 -70.347849,-31.782749 -70.248875,-33.072047 -70.644771,-35.947863</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  </Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you using to view this KML? If it's Google Earth Pro, then your KML should work as-is (it did for me). Please check how you're using the time slider, as it can be a bit tricky.  If you move only the end handle of the slider, then you're effectively viewing a larger or smaller span of time, along with all features that fall within that span. If you move both the start and end handles of the slider together, then you should be moving a small slice through time, and should see the polygons with TimeSpans appear and disappear as expected.  Let us know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chistiaan!!! I really didn't think of approaching the error this way! Great to hear that it works out his way. I already tested it! Thanks a lot for your help!!